# How come I cannot set a breakpoint inside the Android SDK?

Tags: android

I tried to find the entry point for my app by putting breakpoint at

```
onCreate
```

inside Activity.java, but it never breaks at that point.  Is this allowed or possible?

Here is where I breakpoint

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (DEBUG_LIFECYCLE) Slog.v(TAG, "onCreate " + this + ": " + savedInstanceState);
        if (mLastNonConfigurationInstances != null) {
            mAllLoaderManagers = mLastNonConfigurationInstances.loaders;
        }
 --breakpoint here--->>>>>>>>          if (mActivityInfo.parentActivityName != null) {
            if (mActionBar == null) {
                mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = true;
            } else {
                mActionBar.setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Parcelable p = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(FRAGMENTS_TAG);
            mFragments.restoreAllState(p, mLastNonConfigurationInstances != null
                    ? mLastNonConfigurationInstances.fragments : null);
        }
        mFragments.dispatchCreate();
        getApplication().dispatchActivityCreated(this, savedInstanceState);
        mCalled = true;
    }
```

I tried to break at super.onCreate(), which hit, but when I stepped in, it just steps right over everything once inside.

Comment: If it crashes please add a stack trace.

Comment: I like how people start down voting you for no apparent reasons.

Comment: I assume your question is downvoted because `it crashed` without any detail is considered a lack of research.

Comment: If people can say why they down vote the question, I can improve on it.

Comment: Ok there are not stack-trace. I've modified my question because it didn't crash constantly, it just wouldn't break.

Comment: Fixed, maybe you can up vote me back up, as this seems like a really legit question.

Comment: The question isn't asking why the code has crashed, it's asking why a particular debug technique is not behaving as anticipated - the subject is not the poster's program, but rather the system and tools.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot put it on the method declaration statement(which I feel is correct and of no use). You can put the breakpoints inside the function for the code statements.

Comment: Actually, you can (in latest Eclipse at least).

Comment: @mskw please let us know the version of eclipse you are using

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and I break inside a statement. not at.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-method-breakpoints.html    probably this might help. @mskw

Comment: @grepcode That worked! Thanks, if you put in as an answer I'll make it the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to do so.

```
To create a method breakpoint using the Breakpoints dialog
1) On the main menu, choose Run | View Breakpoints, or press Ctrl+Shift+F8.
2) In the Breakpoints dialog box that opens, click add.
3) Select Method Breakpoint from the drop-down list.
4) In the Add Method Breakpoint dialog box, specify the class name pattern, including the package name, and the name of the desired method.
5)So doing, when the debugging session starts, the application will pause in all classes with the names matching the specified pattern, at the specified method.
```

[link](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-method-breakpoints.html) would provide you more details

Comment: @mskw Please find the response and the link for further details